# FPDF - Line Break Not Working

Tags: php, html, pdf, line-breaks, fpdf

I just started using FPDF and I am having an issue on my document where line breaks will not work.

The Ln() function will return me to the beginning of the same line that I am currently on. This is just an annoyance as I got past it by passing it a set value to space the lines.

My main issue is that with MultiCell(), when it comes to a \n, it just goes to the beginning of the same line and piles all of the text up.

Code:

```
<?php
require_once('fpdf/fpdf.php');
$lineBreak=0.21;
$pdf = new FPDF('P','in',array(4,6));
$pdf->AddPage();
$pdf->SetMargins(0.2,0.2,0.2);
$pdf->SetFont('Times','BU',12);
$pdf->SetXY(0.2,0.3);
$pdf->Cell(0,0,'Part Number:',0,2,'L',false);
$pdf->SetFont('Times','B',12);
$pdf->SetXY(0.2,0.3);
$pdf->Cell(0,0,'Item 1',0,1,'R',false);
$pdf->Ln($lineBreak);
$pdf->SetFont('Times','',12);
$pdf->Cell(0,0,'pn',0,1,'L',false);
$pdf->Ln($lineBreak);
$pdf->Ln($lineBreak);
$pdf->SetFont('Times','BU',12);
$pdf->Cell(0,0,'Description:',0,1,'L',false);
$pdf->Ln($lineBreak);
$pdf->SetFont('Times','',12);
$pdf->Cell(0,0,'desc',0,1,'L',false);
$pdf->Ln($lineBreak);
$pdf->SetFont('Times','BU',12);
$pdf->Cell(0,0,'Quantity:',0,1,'L',false);
$pdf->Ln($lineBreak);
$pdf->SetFont('Times','',12);
$pdf->Cell(0,0,'2',0,1,'L',false);
$pdf->Ln($lineBreak);
$pdf->SetFont('Times','BU',12);
$pdf->Cell(0,0,'Order Number:',0,1,'L',false);
$pdf->Ln($lineBreak);
$pdf->SetFont('Times','B',12);
$pdf->Cell(0,0,'no1',0,1,'L',false);
$pdf->Ln($lineBreak);
$pdf->Cell(0,0,'no2',0,1,'L',false);
$pdf->Ln($lineBreak);
$pdf->Ln($lineBreak);
$pdf->SetFont('Times','BU',14);
$pdf->Cell(0,0,'label:',0,1,'C',false);
$pdf->MultiCell(0,0,"A bunch \n of text where line breaking \n does not work",1,'C',false);
$pdf->Output();
?>
```

Here is how it is displayed:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/w5fxg.png

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You simply have to define a height parameter which is the 2nd parameter of both methods ([Cell](http://fpdf.org/en/doc/cell.htm)/[MultiCell](http://fpdf.org/en/doc/multicell.htm)). For MultiCell the height parameter is meant to be the heigth of each cell that is created/drawn by it - not the total height.

You may try to enable the border on the cells to see what happens if you leave the height at "0".

If you define a height you can omit the height parameter of the [Ln()](http://fpdf.org/en/doc/ln.htm) call because the last used cell height is used automatically.

Comment: Thank you very much! I assumed the default 0 would do default line spacing and never thought twice about it! Simple solution that completely eluded me.